Error with ngx-translate: No provider for TranslateStore
CURRENT BEHAVIOR
When I try to use the ngx-translate/core (16.0.3) with ngx-translate/http-loader (16.0.0) and Angular (19.0.4)
The project is using NX and module federation with standalone components approach.
I get the following error when loading my component:
ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(Standalone[RemoteEntryComponent])[TranslateService -> TranslateService -> TranslateStore -> TranslateStore]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for TranslateStore!
    at NullInjector.get (core.mjs:1670:27)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:2194:33)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:2194:33)
    at injectInjectorOnly (core.mjs:1110:40)
    at Module.ɵɵinject (core.mjs:1116:60)
    at Object.TranslateService_Factory [as factory] (ngx-translate-core.mjs:16:97)
    at core.mjs:2317:47
    at runInInjectorProfilerContext (core.mjs:875:9)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (core.mjs:2316:21)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:2184:33)
handleError @ core.mjs:6813
next @ core.mjs:35628
next @ Subscriber.js:91
_next @ Subscriber.js:60
next @ Subscriber.js:31
(anonymous) @ Subject.js:34
errorContext @ errorContext.js:19
next @ Subject.js:27
emit @ core.mjs:6194
(anonymous) @ core.mjs:6696
invoke @ zone.js:369
run @ zone.js:111
runOutsideAngular @ core.mjs:6550
onHandleError @ core.mjs:6696
handleError @ zone.js:373
runGuarded @ zone.js:124
api.microtaskDrainDone @ zone.js:2325
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:588
Promise.then
nativeScheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:557
scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:568
scheduleTask @ zone.js:391
onScheduleTask @ core.mjs:6319
scheduleTask @ zone.js:382
onScheduleTask @ zone.js:271
scheduleTask @ zone.js:382
scheduleTask @ zone.js:205
scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:225
scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone.js:2528
resolvePromise @ zone.js:2462
(anonymous) @ zone.js:2370
(anonymous) @ zone.js:2386
webpackJsonpCallback @ remoteEntry.mjs:13854
(anonymous) @ default-node_modules_pnpm_ngx-translate_core_16_0_3__angular_common_19_0_4__angular_core_19_0-44e48b.js:1

Expected behavior
A translated literal should appear when rendering my component.
Fresh install of a project using NX, Module Federation with dynamic imports and Angular 19, with ngx-translate/core 16.0.3 and ngx-translate/http-loadere 16.0.0
Then, in my app.config.ts:
import { ApplicationConfig, provideZoneChangeDetection } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
import { appRoutes } from './app.routes';
import {
  provideTranslateService,
  TranslateLoader,
  TranslateStore,
} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { HttpClient, provideHttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';

const httpLoaderFactory: (http: HttpClient) => TranslateHttpLoader = (
  http: HttpClient
) => new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './public/i18n', '.json');

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    TranslateStore,
    provideZoneChangeDetection({ eventCoalescing: true }),
    provideRouter(appRoutes),
    provideHttpClient(),
    provideTranslateService({
      defaultLanguage: 'es',
      useDefaultLang: true,
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: httpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient],
      },
    }),
  ],
};

And in use the pipe my component:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { TranslatePipe } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Component({
  imports: [TranslatePipe, CommonModule],
  selector: 'app-user-entry',
  template: `<div>{{ 'jobKnowledges' | translate }}</div> `,
})
export class RemoteEntryComponent {
}

ENVIROMENT
ngx-translate/core: 16.0.3
ngx-translate/http-loader: 16.0.0
Angular version: 19.0.4
Browser:

[X] Chrome (desktop) version 131.0.6778.139

For Tooling issues:

Node version: 20.18.0
Platform:  Mac

I'll provide any more info in case is needed.

The provideTranslateService already has the provider TranslateStore, you can remove this provider and the code should compile.
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    // TranslateStore, // <- remove this!
    provideZoneChangeDetection({ eventCoalescing: true }),
    provideRouter(appRoutes),
    provideHttpClient(),
    provideTranslateService({
      defaultLanguage: 'es',
      useDefaultLang: true,
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: httpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient],
      },
    }),
  ],
};


public-api.ts - source code
export const provideTranslateService = (config: TranslateModuleConfig = {}): EnvironmentProviders =>
{
  return makeEnvironmentProviders([
    config.loader || {provide: TranslateLoader, useClass: TranslateFakeLoader},
    config.compiler || {provide: TranslateCompiler, useClass: TranslateFakeCompiler},
    config.parser || {provide: TranslateParser, useClass: TranslateDefaultParser},
    config.missingTranslationHandler || {provide: MissingTranslationHandler, useClass: FakeMissingTranslationHandler},
    TranslateStore,
    {provide: ISOLATE_TRANSLATE_SERVICE, useValue: config.isolate},
    {provide: USE_DEFAULT_LANG, useValue: config.useDefaultLang},
    {provide: USE_EXTEND, useValue: config.extend},
    {provide: DEFAULT_LANGUAGE, useValue: config.defaultLanguage},
    TranslateService
  ]);
}


Good observation, but even with the excess import removed, the DI import won't work (at runtime)

@craPkit are you Juan Francisco Ruíz? please share stackblitz with the issue replicated or github repo for debugging further

I'm not, I just had the same issue.

I can't share it because stackblitz don't let me use plugins from nx and I need them in the project, and when using codesandbox also gave some errors and couldn't replicate this one.

Make sure to check the following configurations:

The ngx-translate library must be "shared" in your federation setup. So if you're using @softarc/native-federation or @angular-architects/module-federation, add ngx-translate to each consuming module's federation.config or webpack.config respectively (i.e. for host app and remotes) – especially when not using shareAll.
Also see https://github.com/angular-architects/module-federation-plugin/blob/main/libs/native-federation/README.md#configuring-the-host or https://github.com/angular-architects/module-federation-plugin/blob/main/libs/mf/README.md#new-streamlined-configuration-in-version-14 regarding configuration options.
Each ngx-translate Injectable should only be provided once per Injector, like Naren Murali wrote. When in doubt, use the https://angular.dev/tools/devtools to inspect your (Environment- and Component-) Injectors for duplicates, in order to find the culprit.
In simple cases, you're going to want one singleton (of each Injectable, created by provideTranslateService) at root/environment Injector level. So provideTranslateService in your topmost Injector, i.e. host app. Only for more complex translated component setups (e.g. pre-built library components with their own inlined translations) multiple instances of ngx-translate's Injectables might be necessary.


Hi! I'm adding it as a provider in my app.config.ts (I'm using module federation enhanced with dynamic routing)
So, the TranslateStore ended not being the culprit, but the app.config.ts I was adding it was the microfrontend, and not the host one, because for me it made sense just to add it in the microfrontend I was needing it.
That being said, it seems that all the things must be provided AT LEAST on the host, which I guess is something we have wrongly done in the configuration or something? Or is this normal behavior?
Also, how to share a library using ModuleFederationConfig?

@JuanFranciscoRuíz I've tried to address your questions by updating my answer.
